# Expressions not working in code Angular/TS

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, expression

Why is my {{ expression }} not working?

Ive tried everything and the web browser doesnt recognize this {{ expression }} or ng-bind it simply displays the {{ expression }} like so or not at all when using ng-bind, can anyone help?

Im using VS code and have disabled a few plugins due to unnecessary errors but problem is visible on the browser, tried on Chrome and Safari

From HTML file

```
          <div class="form-label"><strong>For:</strong>
            {{ query }}
          </div>
```

From TS file

```
export class AppComponent {
  query: string;

  constructor() {
    this.query = "Name";
 }
}
```

Expected Result:

(On Browser)

Name

Actual Result

(On Browser)

{{ query }}

Comment: Any build errors during build? Any console errors at runtime?

Comment: @mbojko There is no issue in the code you provided, there should be something else, take a look at your console logs

Comment: No errors reported, no problems with the build.  @mbojko

Comment: Green and good to go :/  @RezaRahmati

Comment: Try to provide a default value for query , so query: string = '';

Comment: @Abdulrahman Its defined here ```   constructor() {
    this.query = "Name"; } ```

Comment: @ConnorsFan why forms module is needed?

Comment: @MayMammaz can you please create a stackblitz for your issue, then we can help you better and most of the time you will find what is wrong when creating stackblitz projetc

Comment: there's something you're not showing us. Check this [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d69vjq) it contains the code you provided and works fine.

Comment: @RezaRahmati https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartstry

Comment: @marcusshep I uploaded my code here, it works on the editor not on my browsers https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartstry

Comment: My server wasnt running properly, after spending 4+ hrs on this i finally got it.  I cant thank you guys enough for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing [BrowserModule](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule) in your `app.module.ts` imports array (this module should be only imported once in the root module).
If you have another nested modules you should use [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule).
Try sharing your app.module.ts if this doesn't work. 
The code you added should work.

Comment: BrowserModule is imported see app.module.ts file https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulartstry

Comment: @MayMammaz your code on stackblitz works just fine for me. Maybe its your browser? Try incognito mode on your own stackblitz link...

Comment: I can also see it works in stackblitz. maybe an ad blocker or browser issue. does it work with other browsers? which browser are you using?